# Google Play Services Jar files Java Docs and Sources

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I am about to use the new Location api in the `google-play-services.jar`. I found the jar but now I want to set up the source and java doc for this jar. Does anybody know what the settings should be. Do I need to download it from somewhere or its already in the sdk when I downloaded google play services.
thanks.

Comment: I found the java doc. its in `sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/docs/reference/` I have not found the source location yet.

Comment: It's closed source, so I don't think you'll find the source :)

Comment: How can we get reference doc using Ctrl+q on the specific code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I got it worked. Here is what was need to be done. I had foolishly added the jar in libs folder of the google-play-services_lib project in `Referenced Libraries`. What I should have done was just edit google-play-services.jar.properties file to have path to the doc. This file is in libs folder.

I had to change the path

`doc=C:/Users/thupten/adt-bundle-custom-indigo/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/docs/reference`

and then I had to remove the google play service jar from the `Referenced libraries` (by default its not there, I had foolishly added it).

Answer (score 1):

Download it from Android SDK Manager ie extras->Google play services

It will be present in  \android-sdk-windows\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject

Create a project and add that library in your project ie right click project->Android->below that add that libproject location of google play services.

Tutorial is given here. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

Comment: I have already downloaded the jar and its in my project. I want to set the source for the google-play-service.jar.